# How to write C# code that auto generate new project (.sln) with simple 'hello world' method?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation

I looked at some examples and I didn't find any example that create new .sln with one simple runnable class (simple console project with main that print hello world)

anyone know how to do it or can point on some example ?

Comment: Do this like you would normally without using a program you wrote. Then inspect the files in your solution. Then write your program to write these files. Why do you need to find an example?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi bcz i trying to do something complicated and i need to know how to create simple sln before i moving to something bigger. 
i need to create project that will create other code project :)

Comment: ref: Microsoft
A source generator is a component that can generate source files that can be added to a compilation object during the course of compilation.

Simpler: a source generator generates new source in your current project. Not new solutions (*.sln), nor projects (*.csproj).



https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/

Comment: @AdamVincent 10x. 
i try this already and kind of what i need - but i did't find a way to add classes on runtime and recompile on runtime

Comment: source generators run at compile time. not at run time.

Comment: YES :) 
but i need something that will on runtime and compile other process .. mean kill the runable process - recompile ( with adding new class ) and re-run again when the reflaction show the missing classes that i will need to create ( using dynamic code )

Comment: This is a weird ask.

Comment: Your asks are mutually exclusive. 

For creating assemblies at runtime, you are probably looking at using the C# compiler itself, or Roslyn.

For loading assemblies dynamically, you are probably looking for something like MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework)

I would do some research into both of these areas and you might get some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use CLI

```
    dotnet new console -n MyConsoleApp
    cd MyConsoleApp
    echo "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, David\");" > Program.cs  //OSX
    echo 'Console.WriteLine("Hello, David");' > Program.cs;   //Windows
    dotnet run
```

You can run the above code in one line:

OSX:

```
dotnet new console -n MyConsoleApp && cd MyConsoleApp && echo "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, David\");" > Program.cs && dotnet run
```

Windows

```
dotnet new console -n MyConsoleApp; cd MyConsoleApp; echo 'Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, David\");' > Program.cs; dotnet run
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: again ... i need to write code that writing code - auto generate code 

from C# class create new project and add new class with code to this sln.

CLI is possible - but then how i add new class and compile this from my code ?
and if i want to add more 100 classes .. how i adding them on runtime ?

Comment: CLI is your choice! There is no issue using this approach. Just put the above CLI code into a script file, and run with Bash

Comment: i agree .. CLI - but how to add classes on runtime ? not only on creation  ... and compile all together on runtime

Comment: It is so clear that you got the direction. You are trying to ask for full solution? if so, I guess it is a CS assignment?

Comment: i mean how to control the build from code in this case - 
i not know with any api that give me this option

Comment: Updated. You can use echo to overrite the `Program.cs`